# repetition operator in systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a system verilog comparison as follows.

```
module m();
  int count = 4;
  logic [3:0] first = 14;
  logic [3:0] second = 15;
  initial begin
    $display("Second %b\n", {count{1'b1}});
    if(first == {count{1'b1}}) $display("FIRST Equals\n");
    else $display("FIRST Not equal %b and %b\n", first, {count{1'b1}});
    if(second == {count{1'b1}}) $display("SECOND Equals\n");
    else $display("SECOND Not equal %b and %b\n", second, {count{1'b1}});
  end
endmodule
```

This is the output

```
Second 1

FIRST Not equal 1110 and 1

SECOND Equals
```

What I did not understand is the print statements `Second 1` and `FIRST Not equal 1110 and 1`

Why is it printing 1 instead of 1111?

Comment: That's interesting, if a 4 was there instead of count it would work. I'm curious would having `\`define count 4` and then using `\`count` work?

Answer (score 2):

One simulator tool I use generates compiler errors.  According to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), section 11.4.12.1 Replication operator:

> A replication operator (also called a multiple concatenation) is
>   expressed by a concatenation preceded by a non-negative, non-x, and
>   non-z constant expression, called a replication constant

With replication, I think you need to use a numeric constant, like 4, or a constant type, like `parameter`.

```
  parameter count = 4;
```

Another simulator I use generates warnings and produces the results you see.